# How to unit test on controller level in Vert.x

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, vert.x

UserController:

```
class UserController(private val graphRepository: GraphRepository) : Controller {

    override fun installRoutes(router: Router) {
        router.install {
            post("/api/v1/user").handler(this@UserController::addUser)
        }
    }
}
```

Testing route and calling route handler "addUser":

```
@Test
    fun newUserAdded() {
        Mockito.`when`(mockRoutingContext.queryParam("id")).thenReturn(listOf("1"))
        Mockito.`when`(mockGraphRepository.getUser("1")).thenReturn(Promise.ofSuccess(null))
        Mockito.`when`(mockGraphRepository.enrollUser(any())).thenReturn(Promise.ofSuccess(Unit))
        Mockito.`when`(mockRoutingContext.response()).thenReturn(mockHttpServerResponse)
        Mockito.doNothing().`when`(mockHttpServerResponse).end()

        UserController(mockGraphRepository).addUser(mockRoutingContext)

        Mockito.verify(mockRoutingContext, Mockito.times(1)).response()
        Mockito.verify(mockHttpServerResponse).end()
    }
```

The main question is how to test the controller route without explicitly calling "addUser" on "UserController" because I want to make the controller function private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking behavior for types you don't own is generally discouraged for a variety of reasons, such as (but not limited to):

- If the real implementation of the mocked dependency changes, the mock's behavior will not automatically reveal any forward-breaking changes.
- The more mocks a test introduces, the more cognitive load the test carries, and some tests require a lot of mocks in order to work.

The approach that works best for me is to think of these more as integration tests, and avoid the mocks all together.

To achieve this, I've got an abstract `VertxPlatform` class that I extend that contains references to resources I commonly refer to across a variety of tests:

- the `Vertx` instance itself
- a `Router`
- an `EventBus`
- an `HttpServer`
- a `WebClient`

These resources is reinitialized per invocation of each test, and the `Router` is subsequently associated with the `HttpServer`.

A typical test ends up looking something like this:

```
class MyHandlerIT : VertxPlatform() {
  private lateinit var myHandler: MyHandler  // <-- the component under test

  @Before override fun setUp(context: TestContext) {
    super.setUp(context)  // <-- reinitializes all the underlying Vert.x components

    myHandler = MyHandler()

    router.post("/my/handler/path")
        .handler(myHandler.validationHandler())
        .handler(myHandler.requestHandler(vertx))
        .failureHandler(myHandler.failureHandler())
  }

  @After override fun tearDown(context: TestContext) {
    super.tearDown(context)
  }

  @Test fun status_400_on_some_condition(context: TestContext) {
    val async = context.async()

    testRequest(POST, path = "/my/handler/path", params = null, body = null, headers = null)
        .subscribeBy(
            onSuccess = { response ->
              context.assertEquals(BAD_REQUEST.code(), response.statusCode())

              async.complete()
            },
            onError = { error ->
              context.fail(error)
            }
        )
  }
}
```

In each individual test you might have some more case-specific setup. For example, if `MyHandler` gets results from your `GraphRepository` via the `EventBus` you could setup a fake `Consumer` within the scope of that test that replies with a pre-canned result that server back the values you were otherwise trying to mock.

Hope this helps, or at least inspires some thought!